# Ajax calls working only part of the time

Tags: jquery, ajax

I created these ajax calls to post data entered by customers on checkout. When they click on one of the button, 2 ajax calls are processed.  However the informations are transmitted only part of the time and I am not sure why.  Communication timeout with server? I added an error function in the faulty ajax call to resend the data a certain number of time in case of timeout but it did not work.
I attached an example of the ajax call:

```
$("#notipselect").click(function(event){  
  $("#dialog").dialog("close");
      var dateajax = $("#date").val();
      var timeajax = $("#time").val();
      var utensilajax = $("#utensils").val();
      var Specinstajax = $('#CartSpecialInstructions').val();

      $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/cart/update.js',
              data: {"attributes[date]": dateajax, "attributes[time]": timeajax, "attributes[utensils]": utensilajax, "note": Specinstajax},
              dataType: 'json',
              tryCount : 0,
              retryLimit : 3,
              success: function(line_item) { 
                    console.log("success!");
              },
              error: function() {
                    this.tryCount++;
                    if (this.tryCount <= this.retryLimit) {
                        //try again
                        $.ajax(this);
                        return;
                    }            
                    return;
                }
      });

      function delTip(){
          var params = {
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/cart/change.js',
                data: 'quantity='+0+'&id='+id,
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(line_item) { 
                    console.log("success!");
                  document.location.href = '/checkout';
                },
                error: function() {

                }
            };
          $.ajax(params);
      }
      delTip();

});
```

Comment: can you check your browser console and see if there is any errors? That usually gives a pretty good hint what is wrong

Comment: And the error callback arguments have specifics about the error

Comment: Each time I check the web console there is no error thrown.   The calls fail only some times and I have not been able to pinpoint why.  Could it be due some browsers customer use?